# When to create a class vs setting a boolean flag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oop, object

I have an interesting question to pose; when should one create a model class/object as opposed to setting a boolean flag for data stored in a database?

For example, say I have a Person class that has boolean flags for President, Guard, and PartTime. This class/model is treated differently depending on the value of the flags. So the President gets different privileges in the system from the Guard and from the PartTime(r).

When would one use Single Table Inheritance to represent this information and when would one just continue to use the boolean flag?

My instinct is to convert these to different Objects using STI since this seems more OO to me. Checking booleans seems wrong in some way, but I can also see a place for it.

**Update for clarification**

Let me use another example because the one above has too many cases involved with it.

I am working on a CMS application that contains Pages, a Page can be Public, Private, Shared, Hidden, or Default (meaning it is what you get when you don't specify a page in the url). Right now, we have a Page model and everything is a boolean flag - Public, Default, Shared.

I am not convinced this is the best method of handling this. Especially since we have rules governing what page can be what, i.e., the Default page or a Shared page must be a Public page whereas a Private page is just Private.

I agree with the comment below that Roles for the Person example makes a lot of sense. I am not sure that for the Page example it does.

And to make things more complicated, there can only be one Default page and one Shared page. STI may allow me to validate this, but I am not sure since there can be many default and shared pages in the table (just not associated with a particular site).

**Note**: The context for the question is a Ruby on Rails application, but is applicable for any object-oriented language.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, let's establish what single-table inheritance typically is used for. It is a way to combine the storage and behaviour of multiple things that resemble each other. Sticking to a CMS, an example would be a table with `posts`, which could be either a `Comment` or an `Article`. They share similar data and behavior, but are ultimately different things. Whether or not something is a comment is **not the state of the object**, it's an identity.

In your example, however, whether or not a page is public or private, shared or not, or hidden, appears to be a part of the **state** of the page. Although single-table inheritance might technically work (provided all subclasses are mutually exclusive), it's not a good fit.

State should be implemented in one or more **columns**. An attribute that represents a certain dual state can be specified as a boolean; *yes* or *no*. If a page always is **either private or public**, you can model this as a single boolean column, `private`. If it's not private it's public (or the other way around).

In some cases you may want to store three or more different states that are mutually exclusive. For example, a page could be **either private, or public, or shared** (I don't know if this is the case -- let's pretend that it is). In this case a boolean will not help. You could use multiple boolean flags, but as you correctly observe that is very confusing. The easiest way is to model this as an [*enumeration*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumeration). Or when you lack this (as is the case with Rails), simply use string values with a special meaning and add a validation that ensures the only values you use are one of `private`, `public` or `shared`.

Sometimes certain combinations of different state variables are *invalid*. For example, a page might be a *draft* or *approved* (reflected by a boolean column `approved`); and it is also either *public* or *private* (also reflected by a boolean column). We could decide that a page should *must* be approved before it is made public. In this case we declare one of the states invalid. This should be reflected by the **validation of your model**. It is important to realise that a *draft*, *public* page is not *fundamentally* impossible, it's only impossible because you decide it should not happen.

When creating your model, make a careful distinction between the attributes that reflect **actual properties and states** of the subjects in the real world, and the **business rules** that determine what should be possible and what shouldn't be. The first should be modelled as columns, the second as validations.

---

*Original answer:*

One obvious difference is that boolean flags allow a `Person` to be marked as president **and** guard at the same time. If your model should allow these situations, single-table inheritance will not work for you.

On the other hand, maybe a `Person` that is a president **behaves** differently from a regular person; and a single person can **only** be president **or** guard. In this case inheritance may be a better fit. I don't think you should model "part time" as a subclass, though. That is an attribute in any case.

There is also an important third option, one where you completely separate the **job** or **role** of a person from the model. One **person** has one (or many?) **jobs**, which are or are not part-time. The advantage of this model is that you separate attributes of a person from the attributes of their job. After all, people change jobs, but that does not make them literally a different person. Ultimately this seems to me the most realistic way to model your situation.

Comment: Yep, I agree, and unfortunately, my example was a bad one for the specific situation I am facing. I have updated my post to include the specific problem I am looking at.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer not to use a flag for this, but also not to subclass Person for this.  Rather, attach a Role (or if you have someone who's both a President and a Guard, a set of Roles) with subclasses of Role governing the prvileges.

Personally, I am neither a President nor a Guard, but I am both a Programmer and a Musician, and have a few other roles at times (in fact, I was a Guard for a while simultaneous with being a Student many years ago.).

A Person has-a Role.

Comment: Used a bad example, please see my update above. Completely agree with you though, but I am not sure it works with actual case. I need to think about more though.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that whenever I think "Hm, I have these 3 types of behavior and they do look like subclasses, but need to change at runtime", look at a strategy or state pattern. It usually fits very well and usually also beats a simple boolean flag with respect to keeping responsiblities apart.

In your case, this heuristic would say that you have a Person with an attribute of type AccessRights, which decides if a certain action can be performed or not. Person either gives access to this object or delegates appropiate methods. After that, you have PresidentialRights, GuardRights and PartTimeRights implemetning this AccessRights interface and you are good to go.

Given this, you never need to change the person class whenever a new type of access right appears, you might need to change the person class if a new type of action appears (depends on if you delegate and how you delegate) and in order to add new types of AccessRights, you just add new implementations of AccessRights.

Answer (score 0):

the answer is that it is basically a design decision. There is not an a priori right way of designing an architecture. When you define classes and relationships among them you define an architecture and, at the same time, a language representing the domain of your application.

As any languages it consists of a vocabulary (i.e. Person, President, Guard, etc.); a Syntax (i.e. the relationships you can specify for the instances of your vocabulary) and Semantics (i.e. the meaning of the terms you specify in vocabulary and relationships).

Now you can obviously obtain the same behaviour in possibly infinite way. And anyone would come up with a different architecture for the same system since anyone might have a different way of thinking at the problem.

Despite this there are some criteria you should take into account when designing. 
When you define a Class you are defining a "first order" construct of your language, when you define attributes for a Class you are describing the characteristics of your first order constructs.

The best way to decide if you need a class or an attribute might be this. 
Do Presidents and Guards have different characteristics apart of those they share since they are both person? If that is the case, and they have a number of different characteristics you should create two classes (one for the President and one for the Guard)both inheriting from Person. Otherwise you have to collapse all the characteristics (those belonging to person, those belonging to President and those belonging to Guard) in the Person class and condition their validity to another flag (type). This would be a very bad design

The characteristic of a Page of being public or not is instead something which actually describes the status of a page. It is therefore quite reasonable to model it as a Property of the Page Class