# To subclass or not to subclass

Tags: oop, subclass

I have three objects; Action, Issue and Risk. These all contain a nunber of common variables/attributes (for example: Description, title, Due date, Raised by etc.) and some specific fields (risk has probability). The question is:

1. Should I create 3 separate
   classes Action, Risk and Issue each
   containing the repeat fields.
2. Create a parent class "Abstract_Item"
   containing these fields and
   operations on them and then have
   Action, Risk and Issue subclass
   Abstract_Item. This would adhere to
   DRY principal.

Answer (score 5):

**My Perspective**

Let's say, if you used inheritance. Over a period you have new attributes that are common to only *Action* and *Issue* but not *Risk*. How will you handle this? If you put them under parent then Risk is inheriting stuff that is irrelevant (Liskov Substituon Principle knocking?). If you put then in Action and Risk separately then you are breaking DRY, the initial reason why you started inheritance. Point is Inhertence for re-use is bad. If there is no "is-a" then better not use it and when you are in doubt then there is no real "is-a".

**My Preference**

There are other ways of achieving DRY as shown in below example code. With this addition of new properties my be another *Common2*, addition of new behavior is new *CommonBehavior2* if they are not applicable to all 3 classes; if they are then just change existing *Common* and *CommonBehavior*

```
public class Common implements CommonBehavior
{
    String Description;
    String title;

    public void f() {}
}

public interface CommonBehavior
{
    void f();
}

public class Action implements CommonBehavior
{
    private Common delegate;

    public void f()
    {
        delegate.f();
    }
}
```

Also look at my answer to a similar question with another practical example [Design pattern to add a new class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512184/design-pattern-to-add-a-new-class/4512234#4512234)

Comment: Thank you for throwing in delegation and the good presentation. What do you think of the other way round (see beyond, Task -> Topic). The question is, is the "due date" really part of Action (your delegation) or an artifact of the workflow that does play a role not within dealing with Action, only in the workflow context embedding.

Comment: Thank you for showing Delegate so clearly. What I have for Action, Issue and Risk is indeed a set of common behaviour. Using the delegate approach will make the workings of the classes much clearer when reading the start of the code. Taking example of "Task" below, Action may be a task but Risk is not. The intention of the classes becomes very clear as Action is now: "Action implements CommonBehaviour, Task, MeetingIem", where Risk is: "Risk implements CommonBehaviour, MeetingItem".

Comment: I am glad you understood it. I suggest you also go through my response here to a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512184/design-pattern-to-add-a-new-class/4512234#4512234

Answer (score 2):

Yes, adhering to DRY is usually a very good idea *except* if the classes have very, very different uses (i.e. both apples and cars may be red, still I wouldn't derive both of them from a base class called `ProbablyRed`). In your case, however, I'd definitely go for a base class since the implementations you describe (`Action`, `Issue`, `Risk`) all seem to be some kind of business rule with very similar semantics.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be answering this yourself. As you say, DRY.

Answer (score 0):

The abstract parent class sounds like the way to go.  It will also make it possible or easier (depending on your language) to implement and use functions which act on any of the three items.  For example, you could have a "Get a list of all items raised by {user}" function.

Answer (score 0):

Another facet may become visible if you look at the use cases, probably dealing with different subgroups of the properties.

If for example "label", "due date" and "raised" are used in a todo like application and other properties of "Action" and "Risk" will be prevalent when working on that task, you might consider an aggregation of lets say Task (label, due date,...) and Topic which is a polymorphic reference to things like Action, Issue or whatever will come up someday

Answer (score 0):

I guess I have answered the same question here

[When to create a class vs setting a boolean flag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455188/when-to-create-a-class-vs-setting-a-boolean-flag/4461437#4461437)

Answer (score 0):

**Don't subclass just because objects share some data or operations.** Consider composition as the default way to follow DRY.

In your particular case, only create a parent class if your objects are actually related, i.e. there's a semantic "is a" relationship to the parent class. For example, if Action, Issue, and Risk are all Ticket objects.