# How to structure this group of related Java classes?

Tags: java, oop

So I've been wondering how to best structure some Java classes I have.

The original structure is a hierarchy of three classes:

```
BaseData&Behavior    
|
extends
|
BaseData&Behavior_WithExtraData&Behavior
|
extends
|
BaseData&Behavior_WithExtraData&Behavior_AndAlsoTwoMoreViewsAndCalculationsOnTheBaseData
```

New features are desired that make us want a class like:

```
BaseData&Behavior_AndAlsoTwoMoreViewsOnTheBaseData
```

This class would not fit neatly into the existing hierarchy!

How to create this new class without duplicating code, and in the most elegant fashion?  In Ruby or Scala I could use a Module or Trait, for example.

I'm thinking that the way to do it in Java is to make the `AndAlsoTwoMoreViewsAndCalculationsOnTheBaseData` code go into a class that both `BaseData&Behavior_AndAlsoTwoMoreViewsAndCalculationsOnTheBaseData` and `BaseData&Behavior_WithExtraData&Behavior_AndAlsoTwoMoreViewsAndCalculationsOnTheBaseData` would delegate to.

What do you think is the best way to structure this in Java?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Look at my answer to a similar question. I feel this will be helpful  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565635/to-subclass-or-not-to-subclass/4566107#4566107

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd go with composition.  I prefer it to inheritance, especially in cases like this.  Doesn't sound like IS-A applies to either of the base classes.  You only talk about data; nothing about behavior.  I don't like inheriting just for the sake of data.

Comment: +1. Try to separate out another class or classes that embody the main difference(s) that you want to change from the base class. Think of it as configuring the base, instead of extending. Also, you shouldn't use underscores in java classnames, it goes against the grain of java coding style.

Comment: Also for the "TwoMoreViews" maybe you are looking for a utility class that just visits the data class? Maybe you are looking for strategy implementations you can trade in and out of your class?

Comment: @duffymo in the interest of simplifying my examples I left off the&_Behavior part.  There is behavior associated with all four classes.

Comment: @RMorrisey, sorry for the confusion.  Those are not real class names.

Comment: Thanks guys, when I get back to work on Monday I'll have to look at my code with my pair to see how these suggestions could apply.

Comment: Sounds like an interface might be useful.  Express the common behavior in an interface.

Comment: @Alex - maybe if you change  the names to make it a more real example it'll be easier to come up with explicit suggestions.  But I agree with duffymo's basic preference for composition.